# Why do some stock options have expiration dates for a given month, while others don't?

Tags: options, expiration

Take two stocks, WWE and XPO, both traded on NYSE. Today, May 28, 2014,

### XPO has options expiring August 2014...

[image: XPO options]

### ...while WWE doesn't:

[image: WWE options]

Why is that?

From my experience, the missing expiration month options do eventually show up, so I've linked the screenshots above to Google Finance to check later.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good explanation of this on [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/03/090303.asp). A few quotes summarizing the issue:

> **Not All Stocks Trade the Same Options**
>
> When stock
> options first began trading, each stock was assigned to one of three
> cycles: January, February or March. There is no meaning as to which
> cycle a stock was assigned - it was purely random.
>
> Stocks assigned to the January cycle had options available only in the
> first month of each quarter: January, April, July and October. Stocks
> assigned to the February cycle had only the middle months of each
> quarter available: February, May, August and November. Stocks on the
> March cycle had the end months of each quarter available: March, June,
> September and December.
>
> **The Modified Expiration Cycles**
>
> the original rules were modified, and in 1990, the CBOE decided that
> every stock would always have the current month plus the following
> month available to trade.
>
> Every stock has at least four expiration months trading. Under the new
> rules, the first two months are always the two near months, but for
> the two farther-out months, the rules use the original cycles.
>
> **Adding LEAPS**
>
> If a stock has LEAPS available, then more than four expiration months will be available.
>
> LEAPS are long-term options that, with some exceptions, are no more
> than three years out and usually trade with a January expiration date.
> If a stock does have LEAPS, then new LEAPS are issued in May, June or
> July depending on the cycle to which the stock is assigned.

But you really need to read through all of the article (and follow the links there) to understand the issue, it is quite convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

It's on a different expiration cycle.

Comment: What expiration cycles are there and how does one get assigned?

Comment: as already hinted by Ask Question please add some "meat" to the bone :)  ;)

Comment: Seriously? For the uninitiated: [Investopedia - Definition of Expiration Cycle](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/expiration_cycle.asp)

Comment: Don't think so... both stocks have June and July options, and none of those are quarterlies. Is one changing its expiration cycle after July?

Comment: All months get included eventually.  The roll out of expirations will always follow its cycle.  In July, WWE will have an August '14 expiration. The first two monthlies follow the calendar, next two follow the cycle.